# Postgres LATERAL Query Correctness and Efficiency

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, inner-join, lateral-join

I have the following structure of data, with table names give in bold font and their pertinent column names below.

**common_authorprofile:**

```
{id, full_name, description, avatar_id, profile_id}
```

**aldryn_people_person table:**

```
{id, phone, ...}
```

**aldryn_newsblog_article:**

```
{id, is_published, is_featured, ..., author_id}
```

It bears noting that `common_authorprofile.profile_id = aldryn_people_person.id` and `aldryn_newsblog_article.author_id = aldryn_people_person.id`

I am trying to compute the number of articles for each entity in `common_authorprofile`.

This is how it is currently done:

```
SELECT main.*, sub.article_count
FROM common_authorprofile AS main
INNER JOIN aldryn_people_person
ON aldryn_people_person.id = main.profile_id,
LATERAL 
    (SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) as article_count
     FROM aldryn_newsblog_article AS sub
     WHERE
            sub.author_id = aldryn_people_person.id   AND
            sub.app_config_id = 1            AND
            sub.is_published IS TRUE         AND
            sub.publishing_date <= now()     AND
        aldryn_people_person.id = sub.author_id 
     GROUP BY author_id
    ) AS sub
```

My question is two-fold:

- is this a correct way of doing it, given the table relationship?
- is this an efficient way, i.e., is there a way to improve its speed and readability?

Comment: Are the relationships correct as you described them?  If so, then why are you bringing `aldryn_people_person` into the mix since `common_authorprofile.profile_id = aldryn_newsblog_article.author_id`?

Comment: @MikeOrganek, I believe your observation is correct. This query is a result of a bit of trial-and-error. There are probably redundant bits in it.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping `aldryn_people_person` out of the mix makes this easier to read.

I also prefer common table expressions over subqueries or lateral joins for readability, but CTEs can slow down execution.  I refactor only if speed is a problem.

I would approach it like this:

```
with article_counts as (
  select author_id, count(*) as article_count
    from aldryn_newsblog_article
   where app_config_id = 1
     and is_published
     and publishing_date <= now()
   group by author_id
)
select prof.*, coalesce(ac.article_count, 0) as article_count
  from common_authorprofile prof
       left join article_counts ac
              on ac.author_id = prof.profile_id;
```

The `left outer join` buys you the retrieval of all `common_authorprofile` records.  The `coalesce()` displays missing rows from the `article_counts` CTE as `0`.  You can change the `left join` to just `join` if that is not what you want.

If you have any questions, please comment.

Comment: Thank you. That is an interesting approach. A lot of new stuff there for me. Suppose you wanted to restrict `common_authorprofile.id` in consideration to a set that is provided dynamically. Would you simply add a `WHERE common_authorprofile.id IN ...` clause at the very bottom? As a concrete example, it might be `WHERE common_authorprofile.id IN (1,2)`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Yes, except it would be `prof.id` the way I aliased the table.